# best practice to picasso fetch with match parent in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, prefetch

I'm using Picasso to download pictures and show them in a RecyclerView. I'm trying to prevent the small delay which is happening when I'm scrolling the RecyclerView and Picasso is downloading the new pictures, so I'm using fetch. When I was using exact size for the pictures, it worked well, but now I'm using "match parent" (to work on all devices) in my xml, and since then there is a delay and when I'm scrolling back and forth, it doesn't remember the pictures (delay on the pictures that has been already seen).
I tried just fit() and centerCrop() but it was slow, so this is my current try of solving the issue:

in the adapter (this runs only once) I set a listener to get the exact size of the ImageViews

```
private void preloadImage(final View picture) {
    ViewTreeObserver observer = picture.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            PictureUtil.fetchImage(picture.getHeight(), picture.getWidth());
            ViewTreeObserver mObserver = picture.getViewTreeObserver();
            mObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

In the PictureUtil I fetch all the pictures:

```
   public static void fetchImage(int height, int width) {
    if (height > 0 && width > 0) {
        for (House house : Houses.houseList) {
            Picasso.get().load(getFrontPicturePath(house.id))
                    .resize(width, height)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .fetch();
        }
    }
}
```

and in the adapter again this is how I load them:

```
Picasso.get()
            .load(PictureUtil.getFrontPicturePath(houseId))
            .error(PictureUtil.getPlaceholderPath(context))
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(view);
```

and this is the imageview in the xml:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/house_row_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@drawable/img_small" />
```

So the problem again that I got delay on the images (not like when I had fix sizes) and when I'm scrolling in the Recyclerview the images disappear and load again. What am I doing wrong? Is there a best practice for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know, Picasso stores the values in its cache only for a short time. Correct me if Im wrong

Comment: @AndroidAnton you are right, but when I was using fixed size, it didn't reload the pictures, so I guess the problem should be elsewhere.